# How to convert multiple html files to text files?

Tags: python-2.7, html-to-text

Hello everyone,
                I have a folder full of html files which I want to convert to text files. I am working on ubuntu platform and unfortunately the lynx --dump is not installing for me. Is there an alternative way to convert the html files to text files? Please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This question is tagged `python` so my first choice would be Aaron Swartz's [html2text](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html2text).  It produces test in markdown format.

Python solutions are also possible with [BeautifulSoup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup).

If you like `perl`, here is a simple `perl` script to convert html to text:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use HTML::Parse;
use HTML::FormatText;

my $file = $ARGV[0];
if (not -r $file) {
    die "ERROR: File ($file) is not readable\n";
}

my $html = do { local $/; open(I,$file); <I> };
my $plain = HTML::FormatText->new->format(parse_html($html) );
print $plain;
```